# use winsound in a tkinter program from within a dictionary in python

Tags: python, tkinter, time, functools, winsound

> I have edited the code a bit would this new code work and if not what should i do to get it to work

```
import winsound

import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial # a quick way to make a callback function
import choose_your_own_adventure_game_pt2 as AG
import time
winsound.PlaySound('Adrenaline - Intense Suspense Music (No Copyright).wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)
print('welcome to the')
AG.title()
time.sleep(1)
print('please read each line carefuly once the gui launches')
time.sleep(13)


class Situation(tk.Frame):
    
    def __init__(self, master=None, story='',song=[], buttons=[], **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        story_lbl = tk.Label(self, text=story, justify=tk.LEFT, anchor=tk.NW, font=("Play", 10))
        story_lbl.pack()
        
        for btn_text, new_situation in buttons:
            btn = tk.Button(self, text=btn_text, command=partial(self.quit_, new_situation),padx=10, pady=10)
            btn.pack()
        def song_startup(self, new_sound):
            
            winsound.PlaySound(btn_song_filename, winsound.SND_ASYNC|winsound.SND_FILENAME)
        
            for btn_song_filename, new_sound in song:
                btn_song = tk.Button(self, text=btn_song_filename, command=partial(self.song_startup, new_sound))
                btn_song.pack()

    def quit_(self, new_situation):
        self.destroy()
        load(new_situation)

def load(situation=None):
    frame = Situation(root, **SITUATIONS.get(situation))
    frame.pack()

SITUATIONS = {
    
    None:{
        'song':
        'intro to the game.wav',
        'story':
        
"""



hello player you have been chosen to embark on your first adventure,

this as a button based game so all your decisions are based on a press of a button,

you will play as a character named Sarah who has a wolf goddess inside her, the goddess' name is Winter,

you as Sarah will have the powers given to you by Winter to get through this game but if you use too much
of that power at any given time your game will end,

pretty soon you will be asked a series of questions your job is to choose the answer that best suits your style of playing the game

but be warned you may end up loosing in the end, so without furthur addo lets start this thing

welcome to 
                                      
MOON LANDING EXPIDITION                                             
                                             
male scientist:Hello Sarah can you hear me?


""",

        'buttons':[
            ('YES', 'situation_2'),
            
            ('NO','situation_2_1')
            ]
        },
    'situation_2':{
        'story':
"""


male scientist:good... do you know where you are?
        
        
        
""",
'song':[

('backgroundmusic.wav')
],
        'buttons' :[
            ('yes', 'situation_3'),
            
            ('no', 'situation_3_1')
            ]                  
        },
    'situation_2_1':{
        'story':
"""

male scientist: hmm if you can't hear me
then you wouldn't have responded


""",
        'buttons':[
            ('-_-',None)
            
            ]
        
        },
    'situation_3':{
        'story':
"""

male scientist:alright so do you know why you are here?
""",
         'buttons':[
             ('yes','situation_4'),

             ('no','situation_4_1')
             
             ]
        
        },
    'situation_3_1':{
        'story':
"""

male scientist: you are in a top secret military space center
""",
       'buttons':[
           ('alright','situation_3')
           
           ]    
        },
    'situation_4':{
        'story':
"""
male scientist:well then you seem to have the rare ability to read people's minds

(a second scientist enters the room and starts talking to the first on the other side of the glass)

female scientist:Dr. Smith there has been sightings of foreign aircrafts approaching our location

Dr. Smith: alright Susan we need to transport Sarah to the space explorer

Susan:Yes Sir

(Susan looks in your direction)

Susan:Sarah will you please head to the door behind you and follow the yellow lines on the floor
""",
     'buttons':[
         ('what is going on?','situation_5'),
         ('do not press', 'never_gonna_give_you_up'),
         ('am i in danger?','situation_5_1'),
         ('ok','situation_5_2')
         
         ],    
        },
            'situation_4_1':{
        'story':
"""
male scientist:you were chosen out of five million individuals to take part in a space exploration mission to the planet nexu...

(a second scientist enters the room and starts talking to the first on the other side of the glass)

female scientist:Dr. Smith there has been sightings of foreign aircrafts approaching our location

Dr. Smith: alright Susan we need to transport Sarah to the space explorer

Susan:Yes Sir

(Susan looks in your direction)

Susan:Sarah will you please head to the door behind you and follow the yellow lines on the floor
""",
     'buttons':[
         ('what is going on?','situation_5'),
         ('am i in danger?','situation_5_1'),
         ('ok','situation_5_2')
         
         ],    
        },    
            'never_gonna_give_you_up':{
                'story':
"""
were no strangers to love...


you know the rules and so do i...

iiiiiiiii just wanna tell you how im feeling 

gotta make you UNDERSTAND!!!

never gonna give you up never gonna let you down 

*rick astly.exe has sotpped working you will die now*
""",
    'buttons':[
        ('death', None)
        
        ],
  
                },
    }
def beginning():
    start_button.destroy()
    load() # load the first story
    winsound.PlaySound(None, winsound.SND_ASYNC)
#WINDOW
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x500-500-300')
root.title('Moon landing expedition')
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
#START
start_button = tk.Button(root, text="START", command=beginning)
start_button.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor='c')




#THE LOOP
root.mainloop()
```

> thank you to everyone who has contributed to help me get my code to work I really appreciate all the help I'm receiving and I would like you guys to know that I try every suggestion that comes my way. i hope i can get my code to finaly work as it is really important for me to get it to work

Comment: i have tried placing the winsound.playsound() in the variable itself but it gave me an error

Comment: `time.sleep()` will freeze the GUI

Comment: time.sleep() is for the delay for the cmd to transfer to the gui

Comment: please help i have tried everything i know

Comment: Thank you to all who contributed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `song` item in each *situation* like:

```
'situation_2': {
    'story': ...
    'song': 'situation_2.wav',
    'buttons': [...]
},
```

Then add `song` argument in `Situation.__init__()` and play the song using `PlaySound()`:

```
class Situation(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, story='', buttons=[], song=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        story_lbl = tk.Label(self, text=story, justify=tk.LEFT, anchor=tk.NW, font=("Play", 10))
        story_lbl.pack()
        
        for btn_text, new_situation in buttons:
            btn = tk.Button(self, text=btn_text, command=partial(self.quit_, new_situation), padx=10, pady=10)
            btn.pack()

        if song:
            winsound.PlaySound(song, winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

Comment: @TristanLauzon _"this did not work is there another way? "_ is where ambiguous, be more specific.

Comment: the sound wouldnt play at all but the windows still flowed through like they are supposed to(i was still able to click the buttons and the desired situation still opened but the sound file in the situation never activated)

Comment: i believe the reason it didn't work is because im calling on a situation dictionary that is within another dictionary @CoolCloud

Comment: It works for me.  Try to print out the song name to see whether the function gets the song name.

Comment: it does but what i dont get is why the song doesnt play

Comment: i even tried calling the specific song in the if statment to like if song=='intro to the game.wav':
winsound.PlaySound('intro to the game.wav', winsound.SND_ASYNC)

Comment: Did you give the correct path of the sound file?

Comment: yeah i have the sound file in the main python folder that the code is in

Comment: cause when i call for it before the situation class i was able to get the sound to play

Comment: i even called the full file location

Comment: Then I don't know why it does not work for you.

Comment: it plays the sound when i use the flag winsound.SND_FILENAME

Comment: but the gui doesnt load the needed page

Comment: Then try `winsound.SND_FILENAME|winsound.SND_ASYNC`.

Comment: i just tried that but it didnt want to play the sound then either so imma try and flip the order of the two flags

Comment: and even switching the order of the two flags doesnt work

Comment: do you know why this doesn't work the way it should be?

Comment: @acw1668 i made some edits to my code do you think it will work and if not what should i do to get it to work

Comment: i dont need the help anymore the sound is finnaly working

Comment: i realized it was the length of the wav file